# How to store multiple variables in this code?

Tags: java

I'm writing a program to find out if a number is even or odd and I have all of the code working, but I don't know how to write in other examples. Here is the code I have so far:

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class numberverify
{
    public static boolean isOdd( int num)
    {
        return ((num % 2) == 1);

    }
    public static boolean isEven( int num)
    {
        return ((num % 2) == 0);

    }   
}
```

and the runner:

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class numberverifyrunner
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(in);

        System.out.print("Enter an Integer :: ");
        int num = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println( num + " is odd  :: " + numberverify.isOdd(num));
        System.out.println( num + " is even :: " + numberverify.isEven(num) + "\n");

        //add in more test cases
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "how to write in" other examples?

Comment: I thought that if I wrote: `int num = keyboard.nextInt();
  
  System.out.println( num + " is odd  :: " + numberverify.isOdd(num));
  System.out.println( num + " is even :: " + numberverify.isEven(num) + "\n"); int num = keyboard.nextInt();
  
  System.out.println( num + " is odd  :: " + numberverify.isOdd(num));
  System.out.println( num + " is even :: " + numberverify.isEven(num) + "\n");` it would be able to change "num" but it can't

Comment: basically I want to be able to type in and integer tell if it is even or odd, and then type in another integer and tell if it is even or odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
while(keyboard.hasNextInt())
{
        int num = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println( num + " is odd  :: " + numberverify.isOdd(num));
        System.out.println( num + " is even :: " + numberverify.isEven(num) + "\n");

}
```

The program should quit if you put anything other than an integer in.

Comment: also you dont need 2 methods for that you can use `isEven()` and if it returns `false` it means the number is odd.

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify this code somewhat (and make it easier to maintain) by only having a single method that performs the check. The second method can simply call the first one, for example:

```
public static boolean isOdd(int num) {
    return ((num % 2) == 1);
}

public static boolean isEven(int num) {
    return !isOdd(num);
}
```

For that matter, using a bitwise AND operation here is more efficient:

```
public status boolean isEven(int num) {
    return (num & 1) == 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll add this edit to my code as well.